# How can I view an object with an alert()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to do a debug but I am having problems. Now I try with `alert()`. For example I want to see the value of:

```
var product = { ProductName: $('!Answer_Response[0]').val(),
                  UnitPrice: $('#Price').val(),
                  Stock: $('#Stock').val()
              };
```

When I say `alert(product)` it just gives me `[object Object]`. How can I make alert show what's really there?

Comment: if you want to check any object use console.log(product), this will show your object in browser's developer tools like firebug in firefox.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

you can use the `JSON.stringify()` method found in modern browsers and provided by [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

```
var myObj = {"myProp":"Hello"};
alert (JSON.stringify(myObj));    // alerts {"myProp":"Hello"};
```

or

also check this library : http://devpro.it/JSON/files/JSON-js.html

Comment: Which will not give you the real values of the properties

Comment: @spiel: it gives you a *string representation* using Javascript Object Notation. That may be sufficient here, but if the instance contains methods  (functions) they will not be displayed.

Answer (score 11):

you can use toSource method like this

```
alert(product.toSource());
```

Comment: It works on FF and not in Chrome. Use JSON.stringify instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to easily view the contents of objects while debugging, install a tool like [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) and use `console.log`:

```
console.log(product);
```

If you want to view the properties of the object itself, don't `alert` the object, but its properties:

```
alert(product.ProductName);
alert(product.UnitPrice);
// etc... (or combine them)
```

As said, **if you really want to boost your JavaScript debugging, use Firefox with the Firebug addon.** You will wonder how you ever debugged your code before.

Comment: Thanks. I have now added firebug. The console output is good but can I do more with it? Can I step through code or see my javascript?

Comment: @Melova sure you can. Read the Firebug docs as this is a subject too broad to discuss here.

Comment: Thanks. I will do this. Have a great day.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use:

```
var result = [];
for (var l in someObject){
  if (someObject.hasOwnProperty(l){
    result.push(l+': '+someObject[l]);
  }
}
alert(result.join('\n'));
```

If you want to show nested objects too, you could use something recursive:

```
function alertObject(obj){
 var result = [];
 function traverse(obj){
 for (var l in obj){
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(l)){
     if (obj[l] instanceof Object){
       result.push(l+'=>[object]');
       traverse(obj[l]);
     } else {
       result.push(l+': '+obj[l]);
     }
   }
  }
 }
 traverse(obj);
 return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should really use Firebug or Webkit's console for debugging. Then you can just do `console.debug(product);` and examine the object.

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript native `JSON.stringify` method. To visualise it in a nicer way, you can use, like: `JSON.stringify(obj,null, 4)`

```js
var obj = {data:[{"empmenuid":"1","empid":null,"deptid":"66","aliasid":"66","firstname":"66","lastname":"66","sin":"66","status":"66","empclass":"66","hiredate":"66","seneoritydate":"66","separationdate":"66"},{"empmenuid":"3","empid":null,"deptid":"12","aliasid":"12","firstname":"12","lastname":"12","sin":"12","status":"12","empclass":"12","hiredate":"12","seneoritydate":"12","separationdate":"12","recalldate":"12","martialstatus":"12","gender":"12","pager":"12","locid":"12","jobtitle":"12","jobtitlestart":"12","fullpart":"12","manager":"12","managername":"12","middlename":"12","nickname":"12","paytype":"12","payfreq":"12"}],
recordType : 'object'};

alert(JSON.stringify(obj,null, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
alert(JSON.parse(product) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert (product.UnitName + " " + product.UnitPrice + " " + product.Stock)
```

or else create a toString() method on your object and call

```
alert(product.toString())
```

But I have to agree with other posters - if it is debugging you're going for then firebug or F12 on IE9 or chrome and using console.log is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which property you are interested in:

```
alert(product.ProductName);
alert(product.UnitPrice);
alert(product.Stock);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert( JSON.stringify(product) );
```