# Code alerting 'object Object'

Tags: javascript, php, json, api, jsonp

My code is this:

```
var username = "john";
var password = "doe";

var url = '//api.bos2.cf/?type=verify&username=' + username + '&password=' + 
password + '&callback=?';
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  success: readData(data)
});

function readData(data) {
  alert(data);
}
```

Although this code alerts `object Object` instead of `{'success' : false, 'msg' : 'Unknown API function'}`

Any Ideas as to why this is happening??

Thanks,

CSF

Comment: Because `alert()` wont show you the details. Use `console.log()` instead

Comment: You can't alert actual object...... Insted try alert(data.firstname)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I view an object with an alert()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753931/how-can-i-view-an-object-with-an-alert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to display the raw object. You need to turn it into a string first:

```
function readData(data) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to retrieve the value of "success" that you know of?

Comment: If it is part of the object `data`, it is part of the alert text. If you only want to access the field `success`, use `data.success`. Beware that this is a `boolean`, not a `string`.

Comment: OK thanks. I am aware, I just might need that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
function readData(data) {
  alert(data.success);
  alert(data.msg);
}
```

just go through simple way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer