# Javascript - getPrototypeOf doesn't return the parent prototype

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript snippet:`

```
        var alien = {
            kind: "alien"
        };

        var person = {
            kind: "human"
        };

        var zack = Object.create(person);

        alert(Object.getPrototypeOf(zack));

    </script>
```

`

Not sure why it show zack's prototype is Object instead of person. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its also `person` .But person is an object.its not display with `alert()` try with `console.log()` .If you need to show with in alert use with [`JSON.stringify()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjjluHgxtXTAhXHP48KHZjqA5cQFggrMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON%2Fstringify&usg=AFQjCNHRzqPt6xnPVFwpf_Y2BtQyyTZpIw&sig2=Br-AUjNVjmm1htR1rmioyA)

[`How can I view an object with an alert()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753931/how-can-i-view-an-object-with-an-alert)

```js
var alien = {
  kind: "alien"
};

var person = {
  kind: "human"
};

var zack = Object.create(person);

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(zack));

alert(JSON.stringify(Object.getPrototypeOf(zack)))
```

Comment: Thanks @prasad. Got it now.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.  I cleaned up your code a bit and used the standard naming conventions of classes start with an Uppercase.  Also using the console to log, alerts are so yesterday.

```js
// Define the Alien class, always start with an uppercase
var Alien = function() {

};

// Setup it's prototype
Alien.prototype = {
  kind: 'alien',
  grab: function() {
    return 'grabby grab';
  }
}

// Define a Person class
var Person = function() {
    this.kind = "human";
};

// Copy Alien prototype to Person
Person.prototype = Object.create(Alien.prototype);

// Create a new instance of of Person
var zack = new Person();

// See what's inside
console.log('Prototype function call: ' + zack.grab());
console.log('Zack is a: ' + zack.kind);
console.log('Zack is secretly a: ' + Object.getPrototypeOf(zack).kind);

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(zack));
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see [object Object] is because when you alert `Object.getPrototypeOf(zack)`, the object needs to convert into string to be shown in the alert. Now, default toString() method `Object.prototype.toString` is being called that returns the string representation of an object. If you want to really display some meaningful text in the alert, you need to implement `toString` method on the `person` object itself. Doing this would show your own text implemented in toString() function. The reason why this would happen is the way function lookup happens in javascript. First, object is looked into, then it's prototype and then further into prototype chain. Since in this case lookup would succeed at the object level itself, `Object.prototype.toString` function won't be called and you would see your own text in `alert` box.

```js
var alien = {
  kind: "alien"
};

var person = {
  kind: "human"
};
person.toString = function () {
 return "I am '"+this.kind+"' kind of object";
}

var zack = Object.create(person);

alert(Object.getPrototypeOf(zack));
```

Answer (score 0):

The screen shot is showing the text returned by the `Object.prototype.toString` method. The method is called automatically if an object, constructed by `Object`, needs to be converted to text:

```js
console.log( {} + "" ); // automatic convertion
console.log( {}.toString() ); // explicit convertion
```

What it is *not* saying is that the prototype of `zack` is Object. If you want more information about an object you can use `JSON.stringify` to create a string listing of all its non-function valued properties and their values. (`JSON.stringify` ignores function valued properties by design.)

You could also use equality operators to test if one object is the same as another, e.g.:

```js
var alien = {
    kind: "alien"
};
var person = {
    kind: "human"
};
var zack = Object.create(person);

console.log( "zack is prototyped on person: " 
    + (Object.getPrototypeOf( zack) === person)
);
```