# Bootstrap Tagsinput doesn't return object items

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using Bootstrap Tagsinput and it works fine. However, I recently tried to change it to make it returns object (id and text) instead of just a text but it did not work. It keeps returning `[object, object]` without the actual data.

[image]

HTML:

```
<select multiple class="form-control" id="countryList"  onclick="addToTagsInput();" >
    <option value="AFG">Afghanistan</option>
                    .
                    .
</select>

<input class="form-control" type="text" id="sc">
```

JavaScript:

```
function addToTagsInput(){
    $('#sc').tagsinput({
        itemValue: 'CountryCode',
        itemText: 'CountryName'
    });
    $('#sc').tagsinput('add', { CountryCode: document.getElementById('countryList').value, CountryName: document.getElementById('countryList').options[document.getElementById('countryList').selectedIndex].text });
}

$('#sc').on('itemAdded', function(event) {
    alert($("#sc").tagsinput('items'));//same results if I use console.log
});
```

Where:

`document.getElementById('countryList')` is a listbox listing countries of the world and it has a value of three code letters for the country and text of the country name

Please note that the value and text that I get from the listbox are tested working correctly.

Comment: why are you not closing your selector strings? that is a syntax error.

Comment: also, alert calls .toString on everything. this is what is expected and why we don't debug with alert. use console.log to inspect objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I view an object with an alert()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753931/how-can-i-view-an-object-with-an-alert)

Comment: @rlemon sorry, I missed it but I don't have this syntax error on my code

Comment: @rlemon I get the same results with console.log

Comment: at some point the object is being converted into a string. `({}).toString()` will result in "[object Object]", if you try to add an object and a string in the console.log that will happen, also if you try to add two object. how are you calling console.log?

Comment: @rlemon, yes, I found the answer on the other article. Thank you very much! I was focusing on tags-input on my search